# Rijndael Encrypt and Decrypt in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to encrypt and Decrypt secure data. I have RijndaelManaged and Password DeriveBytes (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Data_Encryption.aspx) for .Net, but same things i need to from iPhone side.

So please some have a idea about this, please do let me know.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Rijndael is AES.  You can use the CommonCrypto API.